# How to use capistrano `fetch_revision`

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

How can I call `fetch_revision` in my deploy.rb? Here is the [link to docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/capistrano/capistrano/Capistrano%2FGit%2FDefaultStrategy%3Afetch_revision) on the method I mention

Comment: I don't have time to investigate a real answer, but I wanted to throw you something hopefully helpful. If you look at git.rake in Capistrano, you can see this used (https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake). Note that they needed to manually instantiate the strategy. The strategy method _may_ be available to you to just call. Otherwise, you may need to reinstantiate it.

Comment: I think I will need to reinstantiate it. I will try your suggestion later. Thanks